# Ubuntu freezes and never launched again

Tags: 14.04, freeze

My problem is while i surfing on internet ubuntu freezes. I can't get any response. Even num-lock is not working. Then i press power button 5 sec and restart ubuntu. it doesn't launch. Screen stays in closed mode. it does not even get a signal.

my workaround is plug out bios battery and plug it in motherboard again. Now i can use my computer normally. But what is the problem? How can i solve it?

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce G 100] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)
```

[image: About This Computer]

My VGA info:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce G 100] [10de:06e6] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce G 100] [10de:06e6]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know some more hardware information about your computer. I've noticed these kind of problems myself, and in my case it was about having a Nvidia graphic card. Could you post some more information?

Comment: i edited it to add hardware info.

Comment: Ok, so you have Nvidia too. In order to check if it's related to the video card, you could try to boot with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter. Then use your computer for some time. If it doesn't crash, then it has to do with the video card driver. Unfortunately, this has the downside that you will have to use a low resolution while testing this, because `nomodeset` usually limits the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Changing bios battery on maincard(motherboard) works. It solved my problem. I don't really know technical details but it's booting without problem.